# Как компилятор С работает с адресами функций?

Tags: c, компиляция, микроконтроллеры, компоновщик, pic

Объявлена функция. Есть задача вызывать эту функцию посредством добавление указателя на нее в стек контроллера PIC16F66. Но, если функция не вызывается в коде, то значение указателя на функцию = 0. Как заставить компилятор присвоить значение указателю на функцию, которая нигде в проекте не вызывается?

Comment: среда MPLAB 4.15 компилятор xc8 1.45

Comment: Это очень зависит от компилятора. Если функция не используется - то компилятор её выкидывает. Такая оптимизация. Обычно, при присваивании указателя на неё явно, компилятор функцию уже не выкидывает.

Comment: @kisssko, от компоновщика, а не компилятора. Автору: посмотрите, как реализован макро `EXPORT_SYMBOL()` в ядре Linux. Он как раз такой трюк и проделывает.